# Bleachbit disk space reducing

Tags: bleachbit, shredding

Before I ask, let me say that I understand how this works, so the fact that I have 0 bytes free doesn't surprise me, as I shut down the computer while Bleachbit was doing its thing.

But now I want to delete these files manually. Where can I find them?
I deleted ~/tmp and some strange folder belonging to root in ~/.
Bleachbit said it has written 4 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I used:

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +500M
```

To find files larger than 500M.

- The output included some very strange file name in the root
  directory.
- This would make sense, as I ran the Bleachbit also for the root directory.
- I opened my filemanager as root and saw 4 files (exactly how much Bleachbit had written), all with similar names (very long, starting with tmp and the rest being random characters and numbers).
- So I deleted them all.